# Capturing IP address from Email in C#

Tags: c#, string

I've written a program to geolocate a senders generic location, however I'm having problems extracting the IP address from my string for example:

```
   public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
    {
        int Start, End;
        if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
        {
            Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
            End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
            return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
```

// I've captured the complete EMAIL'S MIME data to a string (txtEmail)
// Now I search the string ...

```
  //THIS IS MY PROBLEM. this is always different. 
  // I need to capture only the IP address between the brackets
  string findIP = "X-Originating-IP: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]"; 
  string data = getBetween(findIP, "[", "]");
  txtCustomIPAddress.Text = data;
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: `ideas.Any() == false` ...

Comment: What do you get in `data` while debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a regular expression

```
Regex rex = new Regex("X-Originating-IP\\:\\s*\\[(.*)\\]", RegexOptions.Multiline|RegexOptions.Singleline);

string ipAddrText = string.Empty;
Match m = rex.Match(headersText);
if (m.Success){
    ipAddrText = m.Groups[1].Value;
}

// ipAddrText should contain the extracted IP address here
```

[**Working Demo Here**](http://rextester.com/BOOWV76810)

Comment: I guess I forgot mention that the text is contained with a multiline text box. So I' searching the text ("txtEmail) for the  specific line.

Comment: you don't need to search the text for that line. Just pass the whole MIME headers of the e-mail as input to the regular expression. It should do the rest. That's why the RegexOptions.Multiline and RegexOptions.Singleline were ingluded.

Comment: @DevNULL, it looks like my link war broken earlier. I've updated with a working link: http://rextester.com/BOOWV76810 Please see that code..

Comment: I understand, and your're 100% right, but in this case the entire MIME is needed in this case. Pretty critical actually. (Needs to be printed for verification in court).

Comment: can you post an example of the entire MIME? That's what I'm saying. That you can just use the entire MIME, just pass it to the regex and it will extract the IP for you.

Comment: Subject: Re: eXAMPLE
To: EMAILADDRESS@gmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="part1_83ea.3352bc36.3e6ea6e1_boundary"
X-Mailer: AOL 9.7 sub 19
X-Originating-IP: [99.42.208.153]

Comment: There's more but this is what the multiline text box is filled with. The online import to me is the IP address in the X-Originating-IP: [99.42.208.153]. So I can say it to a string and pass it for geolocation

Comment: I've just tryed that input in the demo I made and it works perfectly, returning **99.42.208.153** which is what you wanted.. right? Please see this link: http://rextester.com/RSQQ99732

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Miky but making use of [positive lookahead/behind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs) so we only select the IP address.

```
var str = "X-Originating-IP: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]";
var m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=X-Originating-IP:\ \[).*?(?=])");
var ipStr = m.Success ? m.Value : null;
```